# Proving this integration operator is bounded

Tags: integration, analysis

The operator $T : C[a,b] \rightarrow C[a,b]$ is linear as defined by
$$Tx(t) = \int_{a}^{t}x(\tau)d\tau \qquad ||x||=max |x(t)|$$

How can I prove this operator is bounded?

Answer (score 2):

There are several useful criteria. Trying to show that there exists a real positive constant $C$ such that
$$\|Tx\|\le C\|x\|$$
for every $x$ in the normed space, is quite handy in many situations.

Answer (score 0):

$$
\|Tx\| = \max_{a\le t \le b} \Big| \int_a^t x(\tau) d\tau\Big| \le \max_{a\le t \le b}  \int_a^t |x(\tau)| d\tau \le \|x\|\max_{a\le t \le b} (t-a) = (b-a)\|x\|
$$